# When will deb multi arch support be included in Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, 64-bit, deb, 32-bit

When will deb multi arch support be included in Ubuntu? Is there any ongoing work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.ubuntu.com/testing/natty/beta

scroll down to the note about dpkg.  It makes mention of multi-arch support.

Also, if you check the changelog, I see mentions of multi-arch support:

- http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.16.0~ubuntu7/changelog
- [ubuntu-devel discussion](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2011-March/032750.html)